# Can I make a vagrant multi-machine VM depend on another?

Tags: vagrant

We have a database VM that we always want to start. We also have a VM that works for a distributed configuration, that we only want to start when we're testing that.

My problem is: I want the database VM to start if it's not started when I'm starting the distributed VM

```
...
config.vm.define "oracle", primary: true do |oracle|
...
config.vm.define "distributed", autostart: false do |distributed|
...
```

When I do `vagrant up`, that should just start `oracle`. But when I do `vagrant up distributed` that should start `oracle` and `distributed`. Right now, the latter just starts `distributed`.

Comment: It may be easier to write a script and check if the Oracle VM process is running, If not then go ahead a fire it up that VM and wait a minute or so before you start the Distributed VM. If its Running then go ahead and Start Distributed VM.

Comment: @Tasos it may be easier just to say "ensure oracle is started first" a la `vagrant up oracle && vagrant up distributed`

Comment: yeah that's good if none of the VM's are running  but i mentioned a minute or so Delay for the 2nd Vm as im suspecting the Oracle Vm needs to be Up first before the 2nd Vm for Connection purposes otherwise you start getting DB Connection errors.